# jq: recursion -> nested arrays

Tags: bash, shell, path, jq, recursive-datastructures

How can I parse this json structure with jq? It should loop over leafs (projects and groups) recursively.

My use case is: create project and groups in VCS with CLI. Group can have multiple projects, group can be empty, projects must have parent group created in advance.

Similar analogy would be:

- group = folder
- project = file
- path = absolute path in format `/root-groups/nested-groups-level-1/nested-groups-level-2/nested-groups-level-N`

Thanks

```
{
   "structure":[
      {
         "name":"rootgroup1",
         "type":"group",
         "nested":[
            {
               "name":"nestedproject1",
               "type":"project"
            },
            {
               "name":"nestedgroup1",
               "type":"group",
               "nested":[
                  {
                     "name":"nestednestedproject2",
                     "type":"project"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "name":"rootproject1",
         "type":"project"
      },
      {
         "name":"rootgroup2",
         "type":"group",
         "nested": []
      }
   ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
"rootgroup1","group",""
"nestedproject1","project","rootgroup1"
"nestedgroup1","group","rootgroup1"
"nestednestedproject2","group","rootgroup1/nestedgroup1"
"rootproject1","project",""
"rootgroup2","group",""
```

Try:

```
jq -r '.structure[] | .. | "\(.name?) \(.type?)"'
```

Still not sure, how create a parent path.

Comment: What did you try with `jq` and how did it fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following implements a solution to the problem as I understand it:

```
# $prefix is an array interpreted as the prefix
def details($prefix):
  def out:
    select(has("name") and has("type")) | [.name, .type, "/" + ($prefix|join("/"))];

  out,
    if (.nested | (. and length>0))
    then .name as $n | .nested[] | details($prefix + [$n]) 
    else empty
    end;
  
.structure[]
| details([])
| @csv
```

Given your sample input, the output would be:

```
"rootgroup1","group","/"
"nestedproject1","project","/rootgroup1"
"nestedgroup1","group","/rootgroup1"
"nestednestedproject2","project","/rootgroup1/nestedgroup1"
"rootproject1","project","/"
"rootgroup2","group","/"
```

This differs in some respects from the sample output, but hopefully you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks, it should output also `rootgroup1` and `nestedgroup1`, but Iam trying to understand what is different for these..

Comment: I've revised the program so now it also produces six lines of output.

Comment: Seem there is something missing, third column should reference all parrent groups, for example line `"nestednestedproject2","project","/nestedgroup1/nestednestedproject2"` should look like `"nestednestedproject2","project","/rootgroup1/nestedgroup1"` and should  be propably better, easier and more correct to get rid of first "/" slash. I updated question with expected result. Thanks

Comment: Superb. Thank You.